# How to move treenodes with Gedmo's NestedSet Behaviour

Tags: doctrine-orm, nested-sets

i'm using Doctrine 2 and the [NestedSet extension](http://gediminasm.org/article/tree-nestedset-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2). 
In Doctrine 1 you had the functions `moveAsPrevSiblingOf`, `moveAsNextSiblingOf` and `moveAsLastChildOf` To move nodes around.

In the documentation of the nested extension only moving a node within the same parent is explained. Move a node to another node is not mention. How can this be done?

Are there easy to use functions as found in Doctrine 1 available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation there are examples on how to move the nodes.

```
$treeRepository
    ->persistAsFirstChild($food)
    ->persistAsFirstChildOf($fruits, $food)
    ->persistAsLastChildOf($vegitables, $food)
    ->persistAsNextSiblingOf($carrots, $fruits);
```

Comment: This is not working for me, it completely trashes the tree. If I run 'verify()' after that, I have a ton of errors.